# Ordenar imagenes con lightgallery

Tags: html

estoy usando lightgallery de boostrap, lo que hace es que me ordena las imagenes en filas y columnas, sin embargo cuando son de diferente tamanio estas no se ajustan y conservan su orden, que puedo hacer para ordenar estas imagenes, digamos que al tener una imagen vertical y dos horizontales que ambas se alinean a la vertical.\
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tengo es que al tener dimensiones difrentes sucede lo siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Creo que te convendría utilizar flexbox para minimizar el problema de la distribución de contenido (hay un buen manual en esta dirección [CSS tricks Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)